# xpath get value attributes concat string

Tags: xpath

I have a xml with several attributes like this:

```
<results value="1">
    <result value="111"></result>
    <result value="222"></result>
    <result value="333"></result>
    <result value="444"></result>
</results>
```

Are there any way to get all the values of the attributes and concat to every value a constant string? Output like that:

```
Value: 111
Value: 222
Value: 333
Value: 444
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only pure xpath:

```
//results//result/concat("Value: ", @value)
```

Output:

```
Value: 111
Value: 222
Value: 333
Value: 444
```

Comment: Several observations on this (not criticisms). (1) It requires XPath 2.0. (2) it produces a sequence of strings (one for each line of output), rather than a single string containing newline characters, (3) The "//" operators are redundant; `/results/result/concat(...)` achieves the same result more simply.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that sounds feasible if you relies on [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#string)'s functions library. You could write something like:

```
concat('Value: ',string-join((//result/@value), '\nValue: '))
```

or:

```
concat('Value: ',string-join((//result/@value), '&#10;Value: '))
```

depending on how you encode the newline character.

(tested using https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

Another solution − if you only have a XPath 1.0 parser at hand − would consist in just evaluating `//result/@value`, then post-processing the node-list result so obtained in the programming language that you use.

**EDIT:** if you still need to get a nodelist as a result and only rely on XPath, you should prefer @JackFleeting's answer over my first suggestion.

(BTW I had also thought about the same solution as Jack's first, and tested it on http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath but this didn't work, probably because that online parser is buggy actually).